# Display MathJax dynamically only when there are delimiters

Tags: javascript, mathjax

I have been tweaking with below sample code. The documentation for MathJax isn't very complete. Could someone more experience tell how I should modify the below code so that Tex is only parse when I have specified delimiters like $\alpha$. I would like to make it work like on math.stackexchange.

```
   <html>
    <head>
    <title>MathJax Dynamic Math Test Page</title>

    <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
      MathJax.Hub.Config({
        tex2jax: {
          inlineMath: [["$","$"],["\\(","\\)"]]
        }
      });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full">
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <script>
      //
      //  Use a closure to hide the local variables from the
      //  global namespace
      //
      (function () {
        var QUEUE = MathJax.Hub.queue;  // shorthand for the queue
        var math = null;                // the element jax for the math output.

        //
        //  Get the element jax when MathJax has produced it.
        //
        QUEUE.Push(function () {
          math = MathJax.Hub.getAllJax("MathOutput")[0];
        });

        //
        //  The onchange event handler that typesets the
        //  math entered by the user
        //
        window.UpdateMath = function (TeX) {
          QUEUE.Push(["Text",math,"\\displaystyle{"+TeX+"}"]);
        }
      })();
    </script>
    <textarea  id="MathInput" size="50" onkeyup="UpdateMath(this.value)"></textarea>

    <div id="MathOutput">
    You typed: ${}$
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The sample code you posted takes the contents of the MathInput and replaces the first MathJax element with the new "math" from the MathInput. What you want is to Typeset the MathInput and create new MathJax elements for the delimited text. I setup a jsFiddle example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Zky72/2/

The main change is in the UpdateMath function:

```
 window.UpdateMath = function (TeX) {
    //set the MathOutput HTML
    document.getElementById("MathOutput").innerHTML = TeX;

    //reprocess the MathOutput Element
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,"MathOutput"]);

}
```

Comment: Where did you learn how to do this? Do you know any books on javascript or mathjax? Any reference would be appreciated :)

Comment: The documentation on the MathJax site actually has a section on how to manipulate a math element on the page: http://www.mathjax.org/docs/1.1/typeset.html   As far as how to learn JavaScript here is a stackoverflow question with some good resources: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246/best-resources-to-learn-javascript

Comment: I know this question is old, but I have used this (thanks by the way) and there's a problem, it keeps jumping to the top of the page on key up, also if I leave in the bit that defines brackets, the ENTIRE PAGE gets formatted, is this by design? Do I have to be very careful with brackets now?

Comment: Better than the answer in mathjax official site. Well done! The one on official site messes around with the space and ugly keep the Delimiter unparsed.